# File.createNewFIle() throws PermissionDenied despite permissions are set well

Tags: java, io

We got project running on more enviroments, where in the code is call 
`File.createNewFile().` It works on most enviroment (Win, Linux) but on SunOS it calls `UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively()` and throws

> IOException: Permission Denied.

Permissions for folder are set to 777, (also files created through `FileOutputStream` are created in desired folder without problem).

Can it be handled somehow, without changing the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Java; write once, debug thrice. I couldn't resist, flag it if you must.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue but in windows.

try running ur IDE by right click-> run as administrator.(it is in windows but i m sure thr must be something like this in SunOS)

it solved the problem of rights for me.